# 縦に書かれた数字を一つのリストにまとめる方法

Tags: python, python3

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
と書かれたものを
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
に変換したいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「縦に書かれた」と言うのはなんらかの外部入力を表しているのでしょうか?(テキストファイルとか。) だとすると、一番単純には、1行ずつ読み込んで空リストに付け加えていけばいいだろうと思うのですが? (もっとうまい方法もありそうですが。) 完全に動くものでなくてもいいので、自分でここまでやってみたと言うコードを質問に含めると、あなたの想定(←完全に読者に伝わっていない可能性がある)に適した回答をより早く得られるでしょう。

Comment: 入力元もそうですが、変換先は文字列ですか？それとも「配列ではこうなります」という例ですか？

Answer (score 1):

この数字がテキストファイル `in.txt` に書かれているのであれば、以下のように書けばリスト `data` に代入されます。

```py
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = []
    line = f.readline()  # 1行読む
    while line:
        data.append(line.rstrip())  # line には改行文字も含まれているので除く
                                    # （これだと空白文字も除かれるので注意）
        line = f.readline()  # 次の行を読む
```

Answer (score 1):

外部ファイル入力を想定したワンライナー別解です。

```
import sys

data = [n.strip() for n in sys.stdin.readlines()]
print(data)
```

動作デモ：https://wandbox.org/permlink/pr6r7UrTzkU8rRhj